# SQL: How to replace field when 0 and return same data when it's not?

Tags: sql

I have a column that is returning either nothing, 0 or Budget codes.
The column is ExerciceBudgetaire and I want to replace 0 by '' (empty field) and keep other fields as they are: if 0 then '', if not, return ExerciceBudgetaire

Here is what I did, but it's not working:

```
Select DescriptionLigne,ref1
case ExerciceBudgetaire
    WHEN 0 THEN ''
    else ExerciceBudgetaire
end
from dbo.CODA
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "It's not working" isn't very descriptive. What *is* happening? Do you get an error message? If so, what?

Comment: Yes, the message error is : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one issue where you were missing a comma, which both [current](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376558/15498) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21377103/15498) address.

The second issue is that

```
case ExerciceBudgetaire
    WHEN 0
```

Has a string value coming from `ExerciceBudgetaire` and a constant `int` value, `0`. `int` has a higher [type precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than any of the (`n`)(`var`)`char` types, and so it tries to convert all of the strings to `int`s to see if they're `0`. So, instead, pass it a string constant instead:

```
Select DescriptionLigne,ref1, --New comma
case ExerciceBudgetaire
    WHEN '0' THEN ''
    else ExerciceBudgetaire
end
from dbo.CODA
```

(Both of the current answers also switch the [`CASE` expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) from a simple `CASE` expression to a searched one. However, I see no necessity to do that)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select DescriptionLigne,ref1, case when ExerciceBudgetaire = 0 THEN '' else ExerciceBudgetaire end from dbo.CODA
```

(Assuming `ref1` to be a column)

Comment: Are your only changes the addition of the comma and the (unnecessary) switch from a simple `CASE` expression to a searched one?

Comment: not working:( it says : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Comment: Is `ref1` column or alias?

Comment: the only change is remove the 0 and replace it by blank fields, otherwise, when it's not 0, keep the result as it is.

Comment: ref1 and ExerciceBudgetaire are columns

Comment: Actually the error message is : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DBECHAR-OU' to data type int.

Comment: So does `ExerciceBudgetaire` column have this value?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
DescriptionLigne
,ref1
,CASE WHEN ExerciceBudgetaire = '0'
     THEN 'YOUR VALUE TO REPLACE'
    else ExerciceBudgetaire
end AS ExerciceBudgetaire
from dbo.CODA
```

Comment: Not working:( it says : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DBECHAR-OU' to data type int.